# JavaScript sort table via select dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have dynamically rendered table from JSON data and I want to sort the table by votes and ratings (by ascending/descending) via a select dropdown but I am not sure how... I've tried a few different ways but I always fail.

```
                <label for="sort">Sort</label><br>
                <select name="sort" id="sort">
                    <option value="0" selected>Order By</option>
                    <option value="1">Votes Ascending</option>
                    <option value="2">Votes Descending</option>
                    <option value="3">Rating Ascending</option>
                    <option value="4">Rating Descending</option>
                </select>
```

Here is a link to the code: https://jsfiddle.net/natefr0st/zckrwdaf/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this, you're going to want to use [`Array.sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort). Any kind of sorting you want to do come down to 3 main outcomes: `a > b`, `a < b`, `a = b`. These correspond with the return values `1`, `-1`, and `0`, respectively. So really the only trick is "what are `a` and `b`?" And that is the question you've got to answer. Is it votes? is it name? is it rating? etc.

Here's an example:

```js
var objs = [
  {name: "Bob", age: 30},
  {name: "Susan", age: 35},
  {name: "Jennifer", age: 22}
];

function sortByName(a, b, sortAsc = true) {
  var val1 = a.name;
  var val2 = b.name;
  let result = ((val1 < val2) ? -1 : ((val1 > val2) ? 1 : 0));
  if (!sortAsc) {
    result *= -1;
  }
  return result;
}
// sort by name (ascending)
console.log(objs.sort((a, b) => sortByName(a, b, true)));
// sort by name (descending)
console.log(objs.sort((a, b) => sortByName(a, b, false)));

function sortByAge(a, b, sortAsc = true) {
  var val1 = a.age;
  var val2 = b.age;
  let result = ((val1 < val2) ? -1 : ((val1 > val2) ? 1 : 0));
  if (!sortAsc) {
    result *= -1;
  }
  return result;
}
// sort by age (ascending)
console.log(objs.sort((a, b) => sortByAge(a, b, true)));
// sort by age (descending)
console.log(objs.sort((a, b) => sortByAge(a, b, false)));
```

As you can see, the only thing different between those two functions (`sortByName` and `sortByAge`) is the property upon which I've built my comparison values. Using that, we can create a generic `sortByProperty` function that uses these concepts.

```js
var objs = [
  {name: "Bob", age: 30},
  {name: "Susan", age: 35},
  {name: "Jennifer", age: 22}
];

function sortByProperty(a, b, property, sortAsc = true) {
  var val1 = a[property];
  var val2 = b[property];
  let result = ((val1 < val2) ? -1 : ((val1 > val2) ? 1 : 0));
  if (!sortAsc) {
    result *= -1;
  }
  return result;
}

function sortByName(items, sortAsc = true) {
  return objs.slice().sort((a, b) => sortByProperty(a, b, "name", sortAsc))
}
// sort by name (ascending) using helper function
console.log(sortByName(objs));
// sort by age (descending) calling sortByProperty directly
console.log(objs.slice().sort((a, b) => sortByProperty(a, b, "age", false)));
```

From there, it looks like once you have a dataset, you know how to get it into the table and do the paging, etc. so I won't bother going into that. Let me know if you have any questions!

Answer (score 0):

I added an fiddle sample for you and implemented the first two sorting options ("Order by", "Votes ASC". I guess you can implement the rest of the sorting options :)

https://jsfiddle.net/on863L2m/2/

```
$('#sort').on('change', function() {
    displayMovies(1, $(this).val())
});


switch(sort) {
   case "0":
    movies = movies.sort(function (a, b) {
            return ((a.id < b.id) ? -1 : ((a.id > b.id) ? 1 : 0));
    });
   break;
   case "1":
    movies = movies.sort(function (a, b) {
            return ((a.imdb_votes < b.imdb_votes) ? -1 : ((a.imdb_votes > b.imdb_votes) ? 1 : 0));
    });
   break;
  }
```

Comment: Why not create a generic sort function and pass in whatever property you want to sort on? What if there are 50 fields the user could sort by? That switch statement becomes terribly redundant.

Comment: Also, [`Array.sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) is destructive and will mutate the original array, so in the majority of cases, when sorting, you want to use `objs.slice().sort(...)` so you keep your original data set untouched.